# Variable en ruta de objeto

Tags: javascript, json, url, object, objeto

Estoy realizando un proyecto personal en donde intento recuperar Objetos de JavaScript a través de URL, una especie de servicio RESTful por lo que necesito convertir las rutas de mi URL en rutas JSON para recuperar el Objeto en cuestión, esto lo hago de la siguiente manera:

> Convirtiendo de **URL** a **JSON PATH**:

```
var path = "/example/to/object";
path = path.slice(1).replace(/[\/|\\]/g, ".");
```

Esto resulta en:

```
=> path = "example.to.object";
```

> Mi objeto:

```
var obj = {
  "username":"denyncrawford",
  "example": {
      "to": {
        "object": {}
      }
    }
}
```

Ahora, el problema esta en que normalmente si quiero utilizar una variable para ubicar la llave de un objeto utilizo la siguiente sintaxis `obj[variable]`, pero en este caso utilizando `obj[path]` me devuelve `undefined`.

**¿Como podría solucionarlo? o ¿Existe una manera (*mejor*) de hacer lo que quiero?**

> Ejemplo funcional:

```js
var str = "/denyncrawford/img";
str = str
.slice(1)
.replace(/[\/|\\]/g, ".");

str2 = str
.replace(/[\/|\\]/g, "."); // Sin slice().

var obj = {
  "username":"denyncrawford",
  "denyncrawford": {
    "img":"denyn.png"
  }
}

console.log(str);
console.log(obj[str]);
console.log(obj[str2]);
```

¡Muchas gracias!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prueba de esta manera:

```
 var str = "/denyncrawford/img";
 str = str.slice(1).replace(/[\/|\\]/g, ".");

 str2 = str.replace(/[\/|\\]/g, "."); // Sin slice().

 var obj = {
   "username":"denyncrawford",
   "denyncrawford": {
       "img":"denyn.png"
    }
}

var objeTemp = obj;
var prop = str.split(".");
for (var i in prop) {

  if (objeTemp.hasOwnProperty(prop[i])) {
    objeTemp = objeTemp[prop[i]];
  }
}

console.log(objeTemp);
```